# Coding style in shell script try-except like

Tags: shell

I am learning shell script to facilitate my routine on computer.
In python, there's EAFP style ("Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than for Permission") to handle exceptions.

```
    >>> while True:
    ...     try:
    ...         x = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    ...         break
    ...     except ValueError:
    ...         print("Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again...")
```

Is there such a style in shell script?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you interpret EAFP. In the narrow sense, it refers to a use of exception handling that Python is designed for, but that is in some languages impossible, and in most others both uncommon and strongly discouraged. In a broader sense, however, EAFP is common across nearly all programming languages, and especially common in shell scripting.

*I assume [POSIX shell scripting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html), with a slight focus on [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html). Python code examples are Python 3.*

#### There's more than one way to ask forgiveness instead of permission...

Python is the programming language most strongly associated with the dichotomy of [Look Before You Leap (LBYL)](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl) vs. [Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission (EAFP)](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp). In Python, EAFP typically means allowing an exception to be raised and catching it, rather than checking to see if an operation will succeed before attempting it, which would be the LBYL way.

But those are not the only two possibilities; sometimes it is possible to attempt to perform an operation that does not raise an exception when it fails, but check whether or not it failed after trying it, and act differently based on the result. That doesn't use exception handling, so it feels odd, from a Python perspective, to call it EAFP... but really, it has much more in common with EAFP than LBYL. It is this sort of "EAFP" that is very common in shell scripting.

I think it helps to start off with Python examples, not just because those terms are so strongly associated with Python culture, but also because EAFP, LBYL, and exceptionless "EAFP" can all be demonstrated in a clean and simple fashion in Python. Suppose `d` is of type `dict`:

```py
# EAFP
try:
    print(d['foo'])
except KeyError:
    print('Not found.')
```

```py
# LBYL
if 'foo' in d:
    print(d['foo'])
else:
    print('Not found.')
```

```py
# Exceptionless "EAFP"
v = d.get('foo')
if v is None:
    print('Not found.')
else:
    print(v)
```

#### <s>Checking</s> *guessing* if a shell command will succeed: LBYL

Sometimes we use straightforward LBYL in a shell script. This code, which ships in Debian's and Ubuntu's default `.bashrc` file, checks if one's home directory contains a regular file called `.bash_aliases`. If not, no attempt is made to use it. If so, an attempt is made to source it (to run each of its lines as a command in the current shell). Although this is subject to a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software), the errors that would result in this case are not harmful, so this is a perfectly good design choice here:

```bash
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Suppose, however, that you wanted to go into a subdirectory and perform an operation you would not want to accidentally do outside it. LBYL, at least in its pure form, is a poor choice. In this example, the operation is recursive deletion starting at multiple subdirectories matched by a [glob](http://foldoc.org/glob). (...Which is sort of contrived, in that there are a number of other ways to accomplish it with reasonable safety. If you like, you can imagine that there are more things to do in that directory before and/or after running `rm`.)

```bash
# Don't do it this way!
if [ -d drafts ] && [ -x drafts ]; then  # BAD!
    cd drafts                            # BAD!
    rm -r foo*                           # BAD!
fi                                       # BAD!
```

Here, I tried to check if changing directory to `drafts` would succeed. I checked if it existed and is a directory (`-d`) and if I had execute permissions on it (`-x`). For a directory on a *nix system, execute permissions are what permit me to change into it. (Usually.)

The problem, besides the considerable complexity of this approach, is that I might have missed something. Even if nothing changes, does this really *guarantee* that I will be able to go into the directory? Have I checked everything? *[I leave this as an exercise for the reader.]*

Also, even if I *had* checked everything and ensured the directory existed and was accessible, well... **was.** In this case, the race condition actually matters. If something changes, and I cannot go into the directory, and the `cd` command fails, then I'll be deleting all the precious `foo*` subdirectories that exist side by side with `drafts` instead of the rubbish ones contained within it!

#### Running a shell command and looking to see if it *did* succeed: EAFP?

You may notice the uncanny similarity between those considerations and [some of the reasons](https://books.google.ca/books?id=JnR9hQA3SncC&pg=PA134&lpg=PA134&dq=python%20eafp&source=bl&ots=Jd3TNtZ18s&sig=lAACc-pcAhjNl7KrqQ1x-tJfWuE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf4t-bwaPaAhXOxFkKHaB7Ds04ChDoAQg3MAM#v=onepage&q=python%20eafp&f=false) for using EAFP in Python: [avoiding code that is complex or hard to read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11360880/1038860) and [the risk that conditions may have changed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Exceptions) between [checking and attempting an operation based on the check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use). Indeed, this is much simpler and more robust than the bad way shown above:

```bash
if cd drafts; then
    rm -r foo*
fi
```

You may see that written this way instead, especially if it is desired that the whole thing have a failing exit status if the condition (`cd drafts`) fails:

```bash
cd drafts && rm -r foo*
```

This does not use anything even slightly similar to exception handling. But it doesn't look before it leaps. It doesn't check if the `drafts` directory is present and accessible. It just attempts to change into it. Then, *after making the attempt*, it checks if this succeeded, and declines to continue on to run the `rm` command if it did not.

If by EAFP you mean using exception handling, then this is not EAFP. I understand if you balk at the comparison; after all, this approach existed long before exception handling, and is common in languages like C. But it is motivated by some of the same goals, and it is suitable in many of the same situations.

Of course, this is actually the *more typical* form of asking forgiveness instead of permission in programming. Python is rare in that it is not discouraged--and in fact encouraged--to raise exceptions even in situations that are utterly commonplace.

#### And what of traps?

I somewhat agree with [jas-'s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/435717/11938). Although they are not really the main way errors (in the sense of a command failing) are handled, traps in shell scripting are somewhat comparable to exception handling in Python.

However, there are a couple of important practical differences between traps in shell scripting and exceptions in Python:

- Python programs use exceptions all the time. Most shell scripts used traps rarely, if ever.
- Python exceptions are usually raised from within the current thread of execution (though this is not always so). In contrast, traps are usually triggered asynchronously, and are mainly useful for the purpose of handling asynchronous events like signals sent from a different process or from the system (e.g., SIGINT from when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), though they are not limited to such cases.

Traps are rarely used for control flow in shell scripts and are not all that common for error handling, either, in cases when there are other options. To run a command and discover if it worked, you check its [exit status](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_02). As shown above, control structures like `if` provide a way to do that (and [there are others](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04)).

Answer (score 1):

[Traps](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html) are a shell scripts error handling functionality